# Adding a new entry in dictionary reverts values of previously entered entries' attributes

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm having this issue where adding a new entry with a new key in a dictionary will revert the value of a previously changed attribute.

```
import list_territories as territories

class XmlGeneratorApp:
    def __init__(self, parent=None):    
        self.territory_count = 1

    def add_territories(self):
        self.territory_count += 1
        self.new_entry_name = str("territory%d" % self.territory_count)
        self.new_entry = territories.Territories
        territories.terr_dict[self.new_entry_name] = self.new_entry

    def set_product_price_hd_check_2_false(self, territory_number):
        self.territory_number = territory_number
        territories.terr_dict["territory2"].product_price_hd_checks = False
```

Here's list_territories :

```
terr_dict = {}

class Territories(object):
    def __init__(self,product_price_hd_checks):
        self.product_price_hd_checks = product_price_hd_checks
```

If I call `set_product_price_hd_check_2_false` to set `"territory2"` it as False, then call `add_territories`, it will reset the value of the attribute  `terr_dict["territory2"].product_price_hd_checks` to True. Same thing if I call `add_territories` to create multiple other instances (territory3,territory4,territory5,etc).

It only happens when adding a new entry to my dictionary.

Am I missing something? Is it a known issue that adding a new entry in a dictionary resets the values to init?

Comment: provide a **[mcve]**

Comment: I edited so it's a little more understandable.

Comment: *little more understandable*? In SO we require that it be completely understandable.

Comment: Pardon me, I still have troubles understanding what is "understandable" and what is not sometimes.
I edited with the specific entries and functions, as well as trimming some fat for pyqt5.

Comment: To understand what I mean you must read the link **[MCVE]**

Comment: Edited to remove everything regarding pyqt as it is not necessarily related.